# Adding a symbol in file name using a Power Shell

Tags: powershell

I've got a bunch of pdf files with different names, but all of them have a specific 7 digit number at the end of the file name. I need to rename these files by adding a space before that 7 digit number. What would be a PowerShell script for that?

Thank you.

Comment: SO is not a script writing service, your own effort (a code sample with your work so far) is required for us to assist you.

Comment: Try to select all files with `Get-ChildItem`. You can then use `Rename-Item`.

Answer (score 1):

P.S. Figured this out myself, thanks anyway :)

```
$filter = "*.pdf"
$path = "C:\temp"

$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter

ForEach ($file in $files) {

      $space_position = $file.Name.Length - 11
      $new_file_name = $file.Name.insert($space_position,' ')
      Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName $new_file_name
     
}
```